# Diagonalizing some matrices arising from Fourier transform on $S_n$.

Tags: markov-chains, matrices, symmetric-groups, rt.representation-theory

Consider the function $f$ on $S_n$ which equals $1/n$ on all adjacent transpositions $(i,i+1)$, where we let $n+1 = 1$, and $0$ otherwise, and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\rho)$ evaluated at the irreducible representations.

Recall the irreducible representations of $S_n$ are indexed by the set of partitions of $n$. Partitions here are written as a finite non-increasing sequence of positive integers that add up to $n$.

When $\rho$ is the representation corresponding to the partition $(n)$, the matrix $\hat{f}(\rho)$ is simply the $1 \times 1$ matrix $[1]$.

When $\rho$ is the representation corresponding to the partition $(n-1,1)$, the resulting matrix $\hat{f}(\rho)$ can be explicitly diagonalized, since it can be extended into a cyclic matrix on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The eigenvalues are simply $\cos \frac{2\pi k}{n}$ where $k = 1, \ldots n-1$. Therefore the spectral gap for that matrix (the smallest gap between $1$ and an eigenvalue not equal to $1$) is simply

$$1-\cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} = 1-\cos \frac{2(n-1)\pi}{n} =  \frac{2 \pi^2}{n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$.

the following questions are in increasing levels of difficulty and are interesting to Markov chain theorists:

1. Is it true that all other eigenvalues of $\hat{f}(\rho)$ for some irreducible representation $\rho$ are strictly less than $1-\cos \frac{2 \pi}{n}$ in absolute value?

Denote by $e_{\lambda,j}$, $j = 1, \ldots, d_\lambda$ the eigenvalues of $\hat{f}(\rho_\lambda)$, where $\rho_\lambda$ is the representation associated with the partition $\lambda$ and $d_\lambda$ is the dimension of that representation.

1. For any fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, is it true that $ (1-\max_j e_{\lambda,j}) \le (n-\lambda_1) \frac{2 \pi^2}{n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$, for $n-\lambda_1 \le k$? Here $\lambda_1$ denotes the longest part of the partition $\lambda$.
2. If  $\lambda > \lambda'$ in the sense that one can move blocks in the Ferrers diagram of $\lambda'$ in the up and right direction to obtain $\lambda$, for instance $(n-1,1) > (n-2,1,1)$, is it true that the spectral gap of $\hat{f}(\rho_\lambda)$ is smaller than that associated with $\lambda'$?
3. Give an explicit formula for $e_{\lambda,j}$. This is most likely not possible.

   This question shows how hard it can be to diagonalize matrices and to understand the representation theory of $S_n$ at a practical level.

Comment: What does it mean for n+1 to be equal to 1?

Comment: Standard convention for writing down permutations sanely: When n=5, it means we talk about the adjacent transposition (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), and (5,1).  I think the "Coxeter diagram" for this is called A-tilde or something, and some combinatorialists like looking at this generating set.

Comment: I added two words. Hopefully that's a bit clearer now.

Comment: What do you mean by "Fourier transform"? (I know about the relation between Fourier transform and irreducible representations, but I don't exactly know what it means in this context.) Does your $\hat{f}\left(\rho\right)$ just mean the action of $\rho$ on the irreducible representation?

Comment: Anyway, your $\rho$ reminds me of the YJM elements in the Okounkov-Vershik construction (see http://www.bprim.org/vershik_okounkov-murli-new-aug07.pdf and http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0503.5040 ), and as far as I remember, they consider the eigenvalues. At least that's some beginning.

Comment: @Darij: Fourier transform of a function $f$ on a finite group is defined as follows:
  $$ \hat{f}(\rho) = \sum_{g \in G} f(g) \rho(g)$$
where $\rho$ is any irreducible representation of $G$. This generalizes the classical notion of Fourier transform on $\mathbb{Z}$, whose irreducible representations are all $1$-dimensional since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, and look like $k \to e^{2\pi ijk}$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your reference by Okounkov and Vershik seems to address the explicit description of irreducible representations of $S_n$, whereas I am interested in diagonalizing linear combinations of one of those representations evaluated at various elements in $S_n$. This problem can be quite hard because of the following elementary observation: even if we know the eigenvalues of two hermitian matrices, we might know nothing about the eigenvalues of their sum. Of course random matrix theory provides some answer to the law of the resulting sum, but those results don't apply to the deterministic case.

Comment: Thanks, so I did understand you right. Actually, I mentioned the Okounkov-Vershik paper because they consider very similar elements of $\mathbb C\left[S_n\right]$, namely $\left(1,i\right)+\left(2,i\right)+...+\left(i-1,i\right)$.

Comment: That is indeed an interesting element. It might correspond to the top to random transposition card shuffling model, for which complete analysis in Markov chain theory is available using coupon collector phenomenon.  

Comment: The link in [darij's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36813/diagonalizing-some-matrices-arising-from-fourier-transform-on-s-n#comment86533_36813) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040

Answer (score 3):

The partition $\lambda = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ answers your first and third questions in the negative direction.
For the irreducible representation corresponding to this partition,
$$
 \rho(g) = \begin{cases}  1 &\text{ if $g$ is an even permutation} \\
                         -1 &\text{ if $g$ is an odd permutation.}
           \end{cases}
$$
Then since $f$ is the mean of a set of odd partitions, $\hat{f}(\rho) = -1$.
This answers your first question since it has absolute value $1 > 1 - \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n}$, for sufficiently large $n$.
$(n - 1, 1) > \lambda$, so it also answers your third question as the spectral gap associated with $\lambda$ is zero, assuming the two-sided definition of spectral gap.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the normal subgroup $A_n$ of $S_n$. It has index two.

The adjacent transpositions are odd permutations and lie in the coset of odd permutations.

Let $\nu$ be a probability on $S_n$ concentrated on this coset. Let $\xi$ be the random walk on $S_n$ driven by $\nu$. Let $\xi_k$ be its position after $k$ transitions.

As the subgroup is normal, the random walk is concentrated on $A_n$ for $k$ even and the other coset for $k$ odd.

Therefore the convolution powers of $\nu$ do not converge to the uniform distribution and the random walk is periodic.

This means that there is more than one eigenvalue of absolute value one.

Your function $f$ is such a probability.

In fact the random walk driven by $f$ is reversible and so the stochastic operator is self-adjoint and so $-1$ is an eigenvalue.

This doesn't happen with the standard random transposition shuffle because that is a lazy random walk. If the laziness was taken out it would not converge either.